# Azure file share - set up to block two people from editing same file

Tags: azure, file, concurrency, share

I'm doing a test with Azure Storage (file type) by mounting the share on two computers. I uploaded some files and went to test the issue of blocking for editing in the case of an already opened file. I realized that more than one person can open the file that is stored in Azure and dictate it, and with that the last recording wins. That's right? How can I configure it for editing blocking, when the file is already open on another computer? It's not chek-out / chek-in ... it's just like what SMB does locally.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/managing-file-locks 

Maybe? Didn't put as answer because I didn't read it thoroughly enough.

Comment: my problem are program files ... for example a DWG (AutoCad) ... when it is stored in Azure File Share the editing by two people at the same time is allowed (Last to record wins) ... which is a risk ... the right thing would be a pessimistic concurrency (only one at a time can edit the file)